# How track each function in my project

Tags: java

How to track my projects like let's say i have 5 different projects which are already in production and i want to know which user in a single day how many times login to my application out of 5 application and after login how many times he clicked on a button or how many times he/she click on a function provided by the application. Now i want to track all these things without doing maximum changes in existing code?

Comment: you can do it with Spring AOP also ? but are you using Spring AOP ?

Comment: The thing you are looking for is `LogManager` see example http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html, this is used for logging application's activity as far i understand, you are talking about Web Applications so you can take input of remote address IP and that person is client for you untill he logged in your application and provide his credentials.
You can manage your logger manager in separate `.log` files of different application

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can think of is through logging, using log4j or something similar.  Also, maybe checkout [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/download/?ac=ga0508_s_splunk&_kk=splunk&_kt=0d0ee68f-00b5-441f-966d-e7b6c9228ad1&gclid=CMiB8-yL5b0CFSdn7AodF3MAFQ).

Comment: I am expecting like a complete live report which is nothing but another project which will track my other 5 project. I want a bug or tracker which i will place in my other 5 project and that bug or tracker will help me to know the complete user and users usage of funtion in that project.

Comment: Well, I probably don't have a solution then.  However I have heard of  [jgoogleanalytics](https://code.google.com/p/jgoogleanalytics/) but I've never actually used it.  Perhaps that is more along the lines of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If it is JavaEE web application, You can use

> Java Servlet Filter

for auditing where information about operating requests and the outcome of those requests can be collected, stored, and distributed.Initially you can store these data in database and later on you can analyze it using different application.